# how to check in c++ whether a managed pointer is invalid?

Tags: c++, .net, command-line-interface

We have the following:

```
int* a;
if(!a) //if(a == NULL) also do that
a = new int;
```

and the question is how to do that with int^?

```
int^ a;
if(?????????????)
a = gcnew int;
```

P.S. nullptr doesn't solve them all, for I found the object holding value(nullptr judge as not equal) and immediately after that, using this object cause System.ObjectDisposedException.

Comment: Note that `int* a;` does not initialize `a` with `NULL`, it contains garbage.

Comment: Or something like memory corruption guard (i.e. `0xCDCDCDCD`) if we're talking about the debug version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `nullptr`:

```
int ^a = nullptr;
...
if(a == nullptr)
{
   a = gcnew int;
}
...
```

Comment: and looks like there is a problem, since the pointer is not a nullptr but can be released, and cause a "cannot use released object" exception.

Comment: I found the object holding value and immediately after that, using this object cause System.ObjectDisposedException.

Comment: If `a` is not *manually* set to `nullptr` in the beginning, you will likely receive this exception. Otherwise I don't see a problem if the application is single-threaded. If it's multi-threaded you should use synchronization primitives while accessing `a`.

Comment: I just don't want to dispose that object, and after some time when I want to use that object, the object still holds value but can not access for that exception. why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12200/discussion-between-xxbidiao-and-forgottn)

Answer (score 0):

This should check the variable, but it's really strange implementation and rely on .net GC operation.

```
    try
            {
                ATestFunctionThatUseVariableForNothing(a);
            }
            catch (System::ObjectDisposedException^ e)
            {
                a = nullptr;
            }
            catch (System::NullReferenceException^ e)
            {
                a = nullptr;
            }
```

Anyway there should be another better solution.

A safe thing is to "delete" (set to nullptr) manually if we intended to "delete" that pointer like normal * pointer.